# In storm, can I specify the number of workers a bolt will run on?

Tags: apache-storm, trident

And when using the Trident, if a batch is going to be processed on one bolt, can the batch run on different workers?

Comment: I think it works the other way around. You can suggest parallelism of a bolt, and should probably configure the number of workers according to that. I found this helps: http://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology.html

Comment: Thanks, but what I most want to know is that if I use the Trident batch, can     one batch also be processed on different workers of a specified bolt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can (but it is tricky). And no.

**For 1)** There is no configuration parameter for this. You can only configure the number of workers of a whole topology. However, you can implement a custom scheduler to assign the executors of a bolt to a specific number of workers.

**For 2)** A batch is a "unit of work" an cannot be divided. Thus, it can not be partitioned to multiple workers.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly help~~